# Converting object literal javascript to common language c#

Tags: javascript, c#

How to take the items of address of this code using c# programming language. I have used Newstonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Headerdata);
but it was errror.

```js
<script>
  var Headerdata = {
    config : { debug : false }
    data :{
          "UserData" : {"Name":"Mahtub","server":" mainSever", "isAdmin":true },
          "mainData" : {
            "id": 02134346546 ,
            "unitData" :{
              "units" :6,
               "pageData":{
                 "UserName":"Admin",
                   "Address":[
                     "city":"eastJava",
                     "country":"Indonesia"
                   ]
               }
             }
         }
    
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You are trying to use an array as object, could you not format the array as an object instead.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I got it when i run unit testing?

Comment: This tool is useful: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @NateBarbettini Thank a lot. it helps me full. but i couldn't parse my script above. because it is not json. how can i parse it into c#?

Answer (score 0):

You have an INCREDIBLE number of errors with this object, because it isn't valid JSON (nor is it even a valid object structure).  In order to immediately parse the object without first serializing it to JSON, it will need to be updated as following:

```
{
    "config": {
        "debug": false
    },
    "data": {
        "UserData": {
            "Name": "Mahtub",
            "server": " mainSever",
            "isAdmin": true
        },
        "mainData": {
            "id": "02134346546",
            "unitData": {
                "units": 6,
                "pageData": {
                    "UserName": "Admin",
                    "Address": [{
                        "city": "eastJava",
                        "country": "Indonesia"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that all key names have been properly enclosed in double quotes, a comma was added after the config object, and "Address" is now an object within an array, instead of just an array.

When building an object that you intent to deserialize, you should ALWAYS serialize it with a proper serializer. You should never build it by hand.  In addition, you should always use a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) to make sure it is properly structured.

Comment: @R.Mahtub yes, because your code is incorrect.  You can't deserialize something that isn't properly formatted.  It's that simple.

Comment: it was javascript not json exactly. actually i am getting confuse also with the code. because it wasn't json

Comment: So it means i couldn't take element of address

Comment: You have to encode it to json before you can parse it.  So you can either manually update the code to BE valid JSON, or you need to serialize it to JSON before you deserialize it.  In either case, your object structure is still broken and malformed without the updates and won't be deserializable until you make the fundamental changes I described.